# calculate time difference in rails postgresql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to get time difference as query result in my rails(which has Postgres database)

`Brute Force Approach`

I queried all items from my database and then iterating each record and then calculating time difference in hours which is very slow.

```
1) @image_retouch_items = ImageRetouchItem.where(:status => '0') = Retrieved all data
2) @image_retouch_items.each do |retouch_item|
      latency_date = ((Time.parse(DateTime.now.to_s) - Time.parse(retouch_item.created_at.to_s))/3600).round
   end
```

`Optimized`

I need to calculate the difference of time(hours) in query itself, how to achieve that

```
like - ImageRetouchItem.where(:status => '0').select('(Time.parse(DateTime.now.to_s) - Time.parse(retouch_item.created_at.to_s))/3600).round')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres can do this for you very easily using its internal `current_timestamp`:

```
ImageRetouchItem.where(:status => '0')
                .select("*, round(extract(epoch from(current_timestamp - created_at)) / 3600)::int as latency_date")
```

`current_timestamp - created_at` will return an interval. By extracting `epoch` from that interval, we convert it to a number of seconds, which we then divide by 3600 to get hours and round using the Postgres `round()` function. I went ahead and casted the result as an integer using `::int`, but this is optional.

The image_retouch_item objects will now have a `latency_date` attribute that will contain the latency in hours, rounded to the nearest hour.